# Interface Iterator

Tags: интерфейс, java, eclipse

Использую Eclipse IDE. С java я новичок. Итак, поехали!

Документация говорит, что в интерфейсе Iterator есть три метода:

```
boolean hasNext(); E next(); void remove();
```

Я создаю класс Wtf, реализующий данный интерфейс, после чего жму "add unemplemented methods". Вот что получаю:

```
package wtf;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Wtf implements Iterator<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public static void main (String... args){
        System.out.println("WTF?");
    }
}
```

Мало того, что среда не добавила remove(), так код ещё и работает!!! Тогда я подумал про ошибку в документации, ну мало ли... Добавил в класс следующие строчки кода:

```
@Override
public void remove(){
}
```

И опять всё замечательно!!! Т.е. метод remove() есть в данном интерфейсе, но я его могу не определять в реализующем данный интерфейс классе!!! Что скажите по этому поводу, уважаемые программисты? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Что скажите по этому поводу, уважаемые программисты?

Скажу, что у вас Java 8, а там метод `remove()` в интерфейсе `Iterator` имеет дефолтную реализацию.

**Обновление**

Так надо читать javadoc к той версии Java, которую используете: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

> default void remove()

Comment: Дефолтная реализация?! Наверное, я до этого ещё не дочитал. :) Спасибо!

Comment: Так надо читать javadoc к той версии Java, которую используете: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

> default void remove()